# depth = 1 doesn't work properly and it's saves Null in ManyToManyField and ForeignKey fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django-rest-framework

after adding depth = 1 doesn't work properly

=> models.py file

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.state_name)

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='state_city')
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.city_name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('city_name',)
        unique_together = ('state', 'city_name',)

class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
    state = models.ForeignKey(State,blank=True,null=True)
    city = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

=> serializers.py file

```
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = State

class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    state_name = serializers.CharField(source='state.state_name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = City

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'owner', 'state', 'city')
        depth = 1
```

I have added ForeignKey and ManyToManyField fields in state and city respectively. It doesn't save values in SnippetSerializer while added depth = 1 in Meta Class (it saves Null value in state and city fields). When I add depth = 1 JSON showing related fields as it should be but it doesn't work properly while add new Snippet. Without  depth = 1 it works fine.
I have complex database where tables has many ManyToMany and ForeignKey related fields. Please give me suggestion so I can get related data in JSON.

I have djangorestframework-3.1.2 version. I have used latest version too but same problem. please give me solution and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`depth` is only for representation (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization). If you want to create/update the related fields too you have to overwrite the create/update methods in the serializer (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Greetings.

Comment: I know `depth` for representation but when I add `depth` I am not able to add new entry. without `depth` it works fine

Comment: So, your problem is that when you want to update a Snippet the foreign keys set to null. In this case you can use separate serializers for GET/PATCH.. requests and you only set the depth=1 in the GET one:

`def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = self.serializer_class

        if self.request.method in ('PUT','PATCH'):
            serializer_class = UpdateSnippetSerializer

        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            serializer_class = GetSnippetSerializer

        return serializer_class
`

Comment: I have added `get_serializer_class` in serializer class. but it doesn't work for add or update too. When I ADD or UPDATE the Snippet the foreign key set to null using `depth = 1`. without `depth = 1` it works fine for both ADD and UPDATE Snippet. please help me. @norbert.mate

Comment: Ok, but do you have separate serializer class for GET and ADD/UPDATE? You should have the above method in the view and 2 serializer classes like so:
`class GetSnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`
`    class Meta:`
`        model = Snippet`
`        depth = 1`

`class UpdateSnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`
`    class Meta:`
`        model = Snippet`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Using `get_serializer_class` it work perfectly, But I just want to know that why it doesn't work with simply adding `depth = 1`. I think it should be work.

Comment: Please update the answer to add `get_serializer_class` method in view and two different serializer classes. I will accept it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem and managed to solve it. Since the problem is with the `depth`, I just change the depth value in the `init` method.

```py
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'owner', 'state', 'city')
        depth = 1

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SnippetSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request and request.method=='POST':
            self.Meta.depth = 0
        else:
            self.Meta.depth = 1
```

In the code above, I changed the `depth` dynamically according to what type of request that I made.

But, this is the workaround that I found myself, I'm not sure if this is the best practice but it solve the problem with just little modification.